# Cancel button redirection in force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can we add logic for redirection on the click of cancel button in the below code

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question more? Is like when you click on Cancel the Contact should be created and the Cancel event on whatever form you are, should also get fired?

Comment: When i click cancel , i want to redirect to some custom page and contact shouldn't be created.

Answer (score 0):

We can not handle the cancel button for the standard create record component, but there is a work around, details below

1. We use direct redirection in lightning for new record creation via url
2. set the default values for new record in the url itself
3. set the background context in url to make sure that for user the background page is not empty when he see a new record popup
4. I had done it with following piece of code to make sure when we create new quote user will get redirected to existing opportunity on cancel

   ```
           var navigateToURL;
           navigateToURL = "/lightning/o/SBQQ__Quote__c/new?&defaultFieldValues=SBQQ__Opportunity2__c="+component.get("v.parentRecordId")+",SBQQ__Account__c="+component.get("v.accId")+"&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2F"+component.get("v.parentRecordId")+"%2Fview"+"&nooverride=1";
           var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
           urlEvent.setParams({
               "url": navigateToURL
           });
           urlEvent.fire();   
           $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
   ```

Comment: urlEvent.fire() will open the create record page through the url but which code is changing the behaviour of cancel button.

Comment: this attribute in url  "&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2F"